# How to get rid of the zero '0' numeric from a string?

Tags: ms-access-2007

BEFORE:
Johnson0, Yvonne

AFTER:
Johnson, Yvonne

Answer (score 2):

String functions for Access can be found at http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/replace.php

In your example, code like

```
Replace("Johnson0", "0", "")
```

will do the trick for the particular string `Johnson0`.  If you need to only remove the zero if it is the last character, play with the additional `start` and `count` parameters described in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

You can try executing following query..

```
UPDATE table set 
       columnName = REPLACE(columnName,'0','') 
WHERE columnName LIKE "%0%";
```

This will replace all occurrence of "0" with "".

Comment: Stackoverflow reckons my edit is too trivial so I'll just say it instead ^_^ MS Access uses the * wildcard operator as oppose to %

Answer (score 1):

The answer you submitted clarifies your requirement.  Based on that, you don't need to create a user-defined function if your Access version is 2000 or later.  You can get the same result with the `Replace()` function.

```
MsgBox Replace("Jonson0, Yvonne", "0,", ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a custom function

- See http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/misc/alphanumeric.php for an example.  You could do something similar, but in the loop you would only keep the alpha characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub xxx()
MsgBox RemoveStr0("Jonson0, Yvonne")
End Sub

Public Function RemoveStr0(sString As String) As String
    Dim ipos As Long, sTemp As String
    ipos = InStr(1, sString, "0,")
    sTemp = Mid$(sString, 1, ipos - 1)
    sTemp = sTemp & Mid$(sString, ipos + 1)
    RemoveStr0 = sTemp
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

if you can pull it out to java or another OO lang you can just do a matching using regexes.

Comment: Access is fully capable of this so no need for Java or any other external language.